# Interior (strictly feasible solution) for conic program

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, conic-sections

For a conic program

$\min \ c^Tx$

$s.t. \ Ax+y\geq b,$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x\in \mathcal{K}$

what a strictly feasible solution to this program?

Since $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$, I am not sure whether a solution $(x,y)$ with $x\in\text{int}(\mathcal{K})$ is a strictly feasible solution. Or there is no strictly feasible solution for this program? Thanks.

Comment: If $y$ is a variable, then for any point $x$ in the (relative) interior of $\mathcal{K}$, you can always find a $y$ such that the linear inequality is satisfied with strict inequality.
In other words, choose your favorite $x\in \text{relint}(\mathcal{K})$ and set $y = b-Ax+\epsilon\cdot \mathbf{1}$, where $\mathbf{1}$ is the all-ones vector, for any $\epsilon >0$ of your choice. Then $(x,y)$ is a strictly feasible point.

Comment: @megas strict inequality is typically not required for linear constraints.

Comment: @LinAlg I see. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a Slater point, $(x,y)$ with $x \in \mathrm{rel int}(\mathcal{K})$ and $Ax+y \geq b$ is sufficient (see page 226 in http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf ). The "rel" is relevant (consider, e.g., $\mathcal{K} = \{ (0,x) : x \in \mathbb{R} \}$).